# when sending php email it is blank

Tags: javascript, php

When i send an email using the contact form, the email its self  is blank (no subject and no message or anything!) The email sends perfectly to my gmail but as mentioned, no subject etc.

JS

```
$('#contactform').submit(function(){
    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    $("#message").slideUp(250,function() {
        $('#message').hide();
        $('#submit')
            .after('<img src="img/assets/cbp-loading.gif" class="loader" />')
            .attr('disabled','disabled');
        $.post(action, {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            subject: $('#subject').val(),
            comments: $('#comments').val(),
        },
            function(data){
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                $('#message').slideDown(250);
                $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp(850, 'easeInOutExpo');
            }
        );
    });
```

PHP

```
<?php
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$email = isset($_POST['_replyto']) ? $_POST['_replyto'] : '';
$subject = isset($_POST['_subject']) ? $_POST['_subject'] : '';
$comments = isset($_POST['comments']) ? $_POST['comments'] : '';

$to = 'WhereTheInfoWillBeSent@gmail.com';
$subject = $subject;
$comments = "From: " . $name . ", " . $email . "\r\n \r\n" . "comments: " . $comments;
if (mail($to, $email, $subject, $comments)) {
    echo "Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you soon!";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error sending the email. Please ensure you have filled out the form correctly and try again!";
}
```

HTML

```
form method="post" action="contact-form.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
                            <fieldset>
                                    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"/> 
                                    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>  
                                    <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Subject"/> 
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset> 
                                    <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            </fieldset>
                            <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Comment: So start digging yourself: first open your browsers development console and check if the ajax post actually sends the expected values. If so, then next dump the `$_POST` superglobal into a log file on the server side and check if it receives those values.

Comment: check your SESSION... is started? the way you check for `$name=isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';$email = isset($_POST['_replyto']) ? $_POST['_replyto'] : '';$subject = isset($_POST['_subject']) ? $_POST['_subject'] : '';$comments = isset($_POST['comments']) ? $_POST['comments'] : '';` is actually allowing it to" fail" silently.

Comment: the form works...i recieve an email...expect there is no subject...or anything.... so its clear that when the button submit is clicked it triggers to send an email...

Comment: Are the comments coming through? Seems like this: `$subject = isset($_POST['_subject']) ? $_POST['_subject'] : '';` ought to be this: `$subject = isset($_POST['subject']) ? $_POST['subject'] : '';`

Comment: Try to `var_dump($subject);` and `var_dump($comments)` and see if those variables are being set properly.

Comment: okay now the subject works but it is not actually displayed in subject it displays in the email.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it obvious, the data you posting is different from what you expecting.

```
{
     name: $('#name').val(),
     email: $('#email').val(),
     subject: $('#subject').val(),
     comments: $('#comments').val(),
}
```

It means that only these fields with be available in `$_POST`.
Now either you change key name here in JS or change it in PHP like.

```
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$subject = isset($_POST['subject']) ? $_POST['subject'] : '';
```

Comment: now the email works fine, problem is subject and if i enter text in message is dosnt come trough email

Comment: Whatever keys you past as `data` object in JS , only they will be available in `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @anwerjunaid said, you need to change the order of one line of your PHP:

This:

```
    if (mail($to, $email, $subject, $comments)) {
    echo "Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you soon!";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error sending the email. Please ensure you have filled out the form correctly and try again!";
}
```

Should be:

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $comments)) {
    echo "Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you soon!";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error sending the email. Please ensure you have filled out the form correctly and try again!";
}
```

The order needs to be recipient, email subject, and the message content.

If you want to include a from or reply to, then add something like this:

```
$headers = 'From: WhereTheInfoWillBeSent@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: WhereTheInfoWillBeSent@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $comments, $headers);
```